# how to cast multiset datatype to string in flink sql?

Tags: java, sql, apache-flink, flink-sql

when i was doing such query in flink sql:

```
    SELECT COLLECT(col1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY col2
        ORDER BY col3
        ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS col4
    FROM table
```

how can i cast the `col4`, which is a multiset datatype, to string?

i have tried `cast(col4 as string)`, but it didnt work. the exception is `Cast function cannot convert value of type BIGINT MULTISET to type VARCHAR(2147483647)`

OR how can i pass the multiset data to a java udf and then trasform to a string? how to write such udf?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, casting of multisets is limited. The community is [currently working](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17321) on [improving this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21456).

Until then, I would recommend to use a scalar function. UDFs can accept all types. Since the automatic reflection logic reserves the `Map` class  for the MAP type. You have to add a type hint.

```
public class MultisetToString extends ScalarFunction {

  public String eval(@DataTypeHint("MULTISET<STRING>") Map<String, Integer> multiset) {
    return multiset.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21456) actively worked on,   which has to do with supporting of printing but also casting all the structured types to STRING

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).